# How to fix this NullPointerException with selenium and java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run my Automation script, I am launching URL but I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
package lib.Page;
public class LoginPage {
    public static final String URL = null;
    public static final String TITLE = null;
    public static final String EMAIL = null;
    public static final String PASSWORD = null;

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.wait = wait;
    }

    public LoginPage lauchUrl(String url){ 





    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.get(LoginPageData.URL);
    return this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your stack trace for the exact row where you are getting this error. My guess would be this:

```
driver.get(LoginPageData.URL);
```

as I don't see you initializing LoginPageData anywhere.